# Is Hp 2545 Printer is compatible with ubuntu 14.04 LTS ?

Tags: 14.04

I want to know , is **hp 2545 printer** is compatible in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS ?

Answer (score 4):

You can check Linux **compatibility** of HP printer models here:

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/index.html

The list of printer models that are **fully supported** by **HPLIP (Hewlett-Packard Linux Imaging & Printing) Driver** (which is readily available in official Ubuntu repositories) is also here:

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/recommended.html

Answer (score 3):

The printer is not included in the Foomatic ([cups](https://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-Deskjet_2540)) packages.

You can install your printer via [HPLIP](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet_aio/deskjet_2540_series.html)

```
sudo apt-get install hplip
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

Connect your printer to the PC and turn the printer on. Open a terminal and start the installation with

```
hp-setup
```

To use the GUI, start the command

```
hp-toolbox
```

or start *HP Toolbox* in your Dash.

[image]

Comment: Best answer needs an additonal upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Hp printers work under hplip open source drivers. You can find info about support level on its site: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet_aio/deskjet_2540_series.html

According to this your printer works.